# Making a position: fixed element full viewport width despite container

Tags: html, css, responsiveness

I have an sticky navigation element that is `position: fixed` with the following styling:

```css
.sticky_product_form {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: white;
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 1000;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
}
```

This displays at the bottom of the viewport when a certain condition is met. It is within a container div, and the problem is that I cannot move this element out of this structure. It has a gap on the left side that is not margin or padding (i don't believe, through dev tools). I cannot pinpoint the cause. I have tried to use `100vw` but this doesn't make it any larger than it already is. How can I make this full width regardless of the container?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the horizontal placement, so adding "left: 0;" will position the div to the left of the screen regardless of the container.

Your css:

```
.sticky_product_form {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

A pen for visual:https://codepen.io/sidraish/pen/mdRLvaM